# Convert classic nested loops with multiple if/else with Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need some guidance on what can be done here using Java Streams. I have the 2D Arrray of test[][] object which holds row, col and value inside. in order to produce different representation, I loop through and manually append different characters to do that.

```
public class Test{
    private Point[][] test;   // like a rectangle
    ...
}

public String someFunction() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(150);
    for (int row = 0; r < 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; c < 15; col++) {
            if (test[row][col].getVal() == 1) {
                result.append('L');
            } else if (test[row][col].getVal() == 2) {
                result.append('M');
            } else if (test[row][col].getVal() == 10) {
                result.append('N');
            } else {
                result.append(' ');
            }
        }
        result.append('\n');
    }
    return result.toString();
 }
```

Also, Generally how does the streams work with 2 loops, some good examples would be great help.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `test` ? Also String comparison should be done with equals, and not ==

Comment: @Michael - corrected ! just to show sample comparision

Comment: @azro - corrected! and added, I need some idea how to replace these loops and ifs.. using the stream or is it too much effort and messier than the current one?

Comment: Keep in mind, just because streams are 'newer', doesn't mean that it is always better or clearer to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify a bit this code, you can use `for-each` loops, this way you won't need to handle indexes

```
public String someFunction() {
    for (C[] row : test) {
        for (C item : row) {
            if (item.getVal() == 1) {
                result.append('L');
            } else if (item.getVal() == 2) {
                result.append('M');
            } else if (item.getVal() == 10) {
                result.append('N');
            } else {
                result.append(' ');
            }
        }
        result.append('\n');
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

You won't win something by using the Stream version  because you're doing easy thing just iterating an array so the classic loop is nice, but here it is

```
public static String someFunction() {
    return Arrays.stream(test)
            .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row).map(item -> {
                switch (item.getVal()) {
                    case 1:
                        return "L";
                    case 2:
                        return "M";
                    case 10:
                        return "N";
                    default:
                        return " ";
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.joining()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

---

And if you want to see it, the Stream version with the indices

```
public String someFunction() {
    return IntStream.range(0, test.length).mapToObj(rowIdx -> IntStream.range(0, test[rowIdx].length).mapToObj(colIdx -> {
        switch (test[rowIdx][colIdx].getVal()) {
                    ...
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.joining())).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: @Michael don't think so anymore regarding the OP's edit

Answer (score 0):

my solution for the mapping of int to char is to use char array.

`char[] intToChar = {' ', 'L', 'M', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'N};`

this can replace the series of `if` or `switch` with a simple assignment

this can be made simpler with a String and the method `charAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight variation of Azro's answer, since I'd basically already written it.

If the indices are important (i.e. for some reason you want to perform the calculation only on a portion of the full "grid") then `Arrays.stream` has another signature where you can specify those, just as you did in your answer.

From Java 14, you can use switch expressions to make the conversion from point value to character a bit nicer.

You can also also use `StringBuilder`s in a similar way as your iterative example. `Collectors.joining` works in a similar way but it is not able to pre-allocate the right amount of space. Almost certainly irrelevant for 150 characters, but I thought it made an interesting example anyway.

```
return Arrays.stream(test, 0, 10)
    .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row, 0, 15)
        .map(ValueSource::getVal)
        .map(val -> switch(val) {
            case 1 ->  'L';
            case 2 ->  'M';
            case 10 -> 'N';
            default -> ' ';
        })
        .collect(Collector.of(() -> new StringBuilder(row.length), StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append))
    )
    .collect(Collector.of(() -> new StringBuilder(150), StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString));
```